# Yield return IEnumerable<IEnumerable<...>>

Tags: c#, linq, deferred-execution

The following code creates an intermediate instance of `List<string>` and append values to it before yield return it. Is there a good way to avoid creating the instance and yield return the cell values directly?

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> GetStrValues()
{
    ......
        foreach (var r in rows)
        {
            var row = new List<string>();
            foreach (var c in r.Cells())
            {
                var value = getCellStr(c);
                row.Add(value);
            }
            yield return row;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid creating the list, you can use LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> GetStrValues()
{
     return rows.Select(r => r.Cells().Select(getCellStr));
}
```

This will execute lazily, i.e. no intermediate list will be created. It's a neat way to avoid allocating memory you won't be needing (unless you are going to iterate several times over the inner `IEnumerable<string>`, and `getCellStr` is expensive).

Comment: Curiously, if I want to flat the result as `IEnumerable<string>`, should I change the first `.Select(` to `.SelectMany(`?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9: yes, that's precisely what `SelectMany` is for, and still uses deferred execution, so that's what you should use for if your intent is to flatten results.

Answer (score 4):

You can get deffered action per cell by using two functions.

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> GetStrValues()
{
    ......
        foreach (var r in rows)
        {
            yield return GetCellValues(row);
        }
    }
}

IEnumerable<string> GetCellValues(Row r)
{
    foreach (var c in r.Cells())
    {
        yield return getCellStr(c);
    }  
}
```

Comment: "Is it a good way to avoid creating the instance and yield return the cell values directly?" this is the question, he already suggests doing that

Comment: I think he is a not a native English speaker and he was trying to say "***Is there a good way*** to avoid creating the instance and yield return the cell values directly?", but maybe I am wrong.